# Configuring ruby 3.1.3 failed

Tags: ruby, xcode

I am installing ruby 3.1 via ruby-install utility on MAC OS (12.6). While execution, I see the following error:

```
>>>Configuring ruby 3.1.3 ...
checking for ruby... /usr/bin/ruby
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for clang... clang
checking for llvm-ar... no
checking for clang++... clang++
checking for llvm-nm... no
checking for llvm-objcopy... no
checking for llvm-objdump... no
checking for llvm-ranlib... no
checking for llvm-strip... no
checking for gcc... (cached) clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/jay/src/ruby-3.1.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
!!! Configuration of ruby 3.1.3 failed!
```

Tried with other utilities and other ruby versions.

Comment: I, as most others I assume, would recommend using a version manager to install ruby. Options include rvm, rbenv, asdf, chruby, and frum. Feel free to take your pick but they will make installing ruby (and multiple versions of ruby) much much easier.

Comment: Fair point. However, the real problem was my xcode version was outdated and somehow messing with other configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your xcode is updated. Installer was not able to find command line tools and therefore the configuration was not getting set - resulting in failure.